# How do I get the pose estimated by AMCL at a fixed rate?

Tags: ros, navigation, pose, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I'd like to know if there is a way to get the 2D pose estimates by AMCL at a fixed rate as is the case for the Hector SLAM in which the topic poseupdate provides the pose estimates at 40Hz with the Hokuyo UTM-30LX.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227260/how-do-i-get-the-pose-estimated-by-amcl-at-a-fixed-rate?/) by [Marty](https://answers.ros.org/users/26023/marty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, not without modifying the code, as amcl running frequency is marked by the /scan messages arrival. Even then, you normally see lower frequencies because if update_min_d/update_min_a parameters are >= 0, it skip scans until the robot moves/turns more than these values (with negative values, amcl publishes poses even when the robot is stopped.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marty](https://answers.ros.org/users/26023/marty/) on 2016-02-25**:
Thank you for your reply Jorge.
I set update_min_d/update_min_a with negative values but I get the following error

Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [laser]: No transform to fixed frame [map].

This error does not occur if the two parameters are positive.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2016-02-25**:
mmm.... I noticed that by inspecting the [code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L989), tried it on Stage simulation and it worked... which ROS version are you using?

**Comment by [Marty](https://answers.ros.org/users/26023/marty/) on 2016-02-25**:
ROS Indigo